# iSCSI Initiator Error

Tags: iscsi

When connecting to iSCSI target using starport it shows connection failed check firewall, when conneting using microsoft iSCSI initiator its shows target error. But there is no problem with firefall on target and initiator, AS i can connect to target port 3260 using telnet. I tried different machine and its working fine, one machine has this problem. Whats wrong this machine ?

Answer (score 3):

What type of machine are you running the target on? What type of Target?

From my experience with several iSCSI targets, MS' iSCSI Initiator is a very reliable indicator to the location of the problem.

The most common reasons for getting this type of error for were -

1. Target was listening on the wrong IP address
2. Under Fedora, the default iptables configuration prevents incoming TCP connection of many types - including port 3260

Regarding Windows' built in rules - At least Win7 works with its built-in iSCSI initiator out-of-the-box

Answer (score 0):

What target are you using? Turn off Windows build in rule of working with iSCSI and create manually rules, allowing access to 3260 and 3261 ports.